# Async reading chunked content with HttpClient from ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: http, rest, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I would like to use HttpClient to read the chunked (in the sense of HTTP 1.1 chunked transfer encoding) content asynchronously.

I am looking at HttpContent async methods at:
[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193663.aspx)

However, in the case of returned Task for byte array, for example:

> The returned Task object will complete after all of the content has been written as a byte array

I am getting chunked content precisely because server doesn't know ahead of time when will all of the data be available, thus I don't know when will all of the content arrive. Rather than waiting, possibly for hours, for the task to complete, I would like to be able to read the chunks as they arrive.

Can I somehow read part of the response content, like have some task that would complete when every 4K bytes of content are received in response?

Is using HttpClient advantageous at all in this case?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using HttpClient.SendAsync you can pass a HttpCompletionOption parameter to tell HttpClient not to buffer the response for you and return as soon as it gets the headers.  Then you can use ReadAsStreamAsync to get a stream that will allow you to pull the data as it arrives.

Comment: Worked beautifully. I used HttpSelfHostServer and made sure that content was chunked. I could follow its arrival in chunks on client side. There was no need to parse manually the chunked content - stream was already de-chunked in the sense of transfer encoding, even if data were available in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient) is a complete example of how to download a file without reading its content to memory with an explanation. Works beautifully.

```
static async Task HttpGetForLargeFileInRightWay()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        const string url = 
"https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/ASPNETWebAPISamples/archive/master.zip";
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, 
HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            string fileToWriteTo = Path.GetTempFileName();
            using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or instead of using `CopyToAsync()` you can read stream by using `StreamReader`

```
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    int bytesCount = 100;
    var buffer = new char[bytesCount];
    reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, bytesCount);
}
```