# Why can't I prevent chunking on my HttpRequest from WPF client to Web API controller?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, http-chunked

I have been battling this for a week now.  See [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195670/why-are-posts-and-puts-readasasync-null-but-readasstringasync-filled-aka) for some additional background.

My `WPF` client makes `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` calls to my Web API controllers.  All was well for weeks.  Then suddenly, *all* of my PUT and POST calls are coming in chunked.  I cannot find any means of preventing it. I strongly suspect I made one central change that impacted everything, but I am exhausted trying to find it.  I've looked back through source control and reinstated old code, and it just refuses to work.

I know of "request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked" and it has no effect.  I can explicity set it to *null* or *false* in my client, and it always arrives in my routine below as *true*.

My PUT/POST controller methods follow this model.  The upshot for me is that my incoming objects ("User" here) arrive as null. But if I do a `.ReadAsStringAsync()` on the request, I get exactly the JSON expected.  But I don't want to rearchitect this app around that non-intuitive pattern; the blasted objects should just arrive unchunked and ready for work!

```
[HttpPut]
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] User user)
{
    if (user == null)
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "User data is null");

    try
    {
        ....etc.
    }
}
```

The "User" object is an Entity Framework object, and is unremarkable.  Simple string, DateTime and numeric properties.

Similarly, and just as infuriating, I can set request.Headers.AcceptEncoding to *null* and it arrives in my controller as *Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate*.

Some links that describe the same problem and symptoms:

- [Issue with .NET Web API and Chunked Transfers](http://mdickin.com/2016/01/26/issue-with-net-web-api-and-chunked-transfers/)
- [Web api 2.1 does not work with a chunked request](https://forums.asp.net/t/1978292.aspx?Web+api+2+1+does+not+work+with+a+chunked+request)
- [How to disable Chunked Transfer Encoding in ASP.Net C# using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464233/how-to-disable-chunked-transfer-encoding-in-asp-net-c-sharp-using-httpclient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clear answer on this, but I finally got it fixed.  It was a long haul.

Don't know how it got there, but in my .csproj I had this:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Rather than this:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
```

And in my App.config I had this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

...rather than...*not* this. I didn't need this stuff. I just took it out and it all started working again.